Windows Search Highlights option is missing from setting (Windows 11)
I'm facing an issue on my Windows 11 Home (version 23H2, Insiders Beta), and I hope someone can help.
Recently, I noticed that the "Show Search Highlights" option has completely disappeared from my search settings. I've tried a lot of troubleshooting steps, but nothing has worked so far:

Manually added the necessary registry keys (based on tutorials found around the network).

Ran SFC /SCANNOW and DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth multiple times (no success).

Restarted the Windows Search service.

Checked my settings, but can't find anything related to Search Highlights


The issue occurred after testing a Linux distribution using a live USB stick, I powered off my PC and removed the USB. Upon rebooting into my default Windows 11 OS, I noticed that the "Show Search Highlights" option had completely disappeared from the search settings. This issue was not present before the Linux test.
What should I do to solve this inconvenience? Has anyone else faced this issue or know how to restore the "Show Search Highlights" option? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[Screenshots below]
First screenshot
Second screenshot
Third screenshot
Fourth screenshot
here are more details regarding my OS version:

Windows 11 HOME edition (x64)

Version 23H2 (OS Build 22635.4225 ni_release)

Windows Insider Program, BETA Channel


Regards.

This might be an Insider version bug. Simply booting an OS from  USB should make absolutely no change to the main drive, unless the USB contained malware or a badly designed installer. Did you make any changes to BIOS to allow USB installation, such as changing boot order, Secure Boot, etc.? Have you reverted those changes?

hi and thanks for the reply.
As for the Linux distribution it was Linux Mint that I tested via Live USB. The procedure to use it was the classic one used to boot the PC in the live USB. After using it I turned off the PC, disconnected the mass storage device and restarted the PC normally in Windows.
I have not made any significant changes to the UEFI / Bios at all.
To be honest with you I was wondering if maybe it was some feature that I should activate with the ViveTool tool (whose id escapes me though) since I tried every way to try to reactivate the "Search Highlights" item.
